# How to implement remove_reference

Tags: c++, types, type-traits

I'm learning type traits and type transformation (modification?), so I came across `std::remove_reference`. I tried to implement it like this:

```
template <class T>
struct remove_reference { typedef T type; };

template <class T>
struct remove_reference<const T> { typedef const T type; };

template <class T>
struct remove_reference<T&> { typedef T type; };

template <class T>
struct remove_reference<const T&> { typedef const T type; };
```

Now when I use it:

```
remove_reference<int>::type x1;        // x1 is int : Ok
remove_reference<const int>::type x2;  // x2 is <type> : ???
remove_reference<int&>::type x3;       // x3 is int : Ok
remove_reference<const int&>::type x4; // x4 is <type> : ???
```

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 and it tells me the type of `x2` and `x4` is `<type>` so what am I missing here ?

Note:

1. I'm doing `{ typedef const T type }` to remove reference and keep constness...
2. I don't know C++ standard implementation of std::remove_reference

Edit: There is nothing wrong with std::remove_reference, I'm just doing this for sake of learning ...

Comment: `const` objects need to be initialized when used. I guess, that's the eror with your code. Note, that you only need to specialize `template <typename T> struct remove_reference<T&> { using type = T; };` as it works with all kinds of lvalue references (also for `T volatile&`). I *think* `std::remove_reference` also strips rvalue references, though, i.e., it would require a specialization for `T&&`, too.

Comment: What is wrong with [`std::remove_reference`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/remove_reference)?

Comment: @nwp there is nothing wrong with std::remove_reference but I said "I'm learning" ...

Comment: You don't need the `const` specializations.

Comment: Also, I don't see the problem here. [Your code works fine](http://rextester.com/live/DPV39563).

Comment: @sleeptightpupper If I don't use const specialization how would I keep constness ?

Comment: @Leo: The `const` will be retained as part of `T`. So, if you do `remove_reference<const int>`, then `T` is `const int`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I'm doing `{ typedef const T type }` to remove reference and keep constness...

You don't need to do that. If you remove the reference from `T&` where `T` is `const X` then you get `const X`. There's no need to specialize for that.

You *do* need to deal with rvalue references though.

So your implementation should be:

```
template <class T>
struct remove_reference { typedef T type; };

template <class T>
struct remove_reference<T&> { typedef T type; };

template <class T>
struct remove_reference<T&&> { typedef T type; };
```

That doesn't change the fact your tests are not valid though. Using a recent build of VC++ I get more useful errors:

main.cpp(16): error C2734: 'x2': 'const' object must be initialized if not 'extern'
main.cpp(18): error C2734: 'x4': 'const' object must be initialized if not 'extern'

This correctly tells you that you are trying to define a `const` without giving it a value. That's not allowed, because it would have an indeterminate (i.e. garbage) value, and you couldn't set it!

That has nothing to do with your `remove_reference`, you'd get the same errors if you wrote this:

```
int x1;
const int x2;   // error!
int x3;
const int x4;   // error!
```

Your tests will work fine if you initialize the const variables:

```
remove_reference<int>::type x1;        // x1 is uninitialized
remove_reference<const int>::type x2 = 0;
remove_reference<int&>::type x3;       // x3 is uninitialized
remove_reference<const int&>::type x4 = 0;
```